# Runtime error '3270' when running VBA code in MS Access 365

Tags: vba, ms-access, runtime-error

I have few legacy Access reports which were created in 2003 but now users have been upgraded to Windows 10 and reports are failing with below error message:

[image: Error 3270]

Clicking on Debug highlights below line:

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery Me.cboChooseQuery, acViewNormal, acReadOnly
```

Me.cboChooseQuery is a dropdown with query names. These reports used to work on Windows 7 and Access 2016, does it mean its deprecated in Windows 10/Access 365? Any suggestion? is there alternative to DoCmd which I can try?

Comment: Unlikely related to Windows 10, chances are it's related to Office 365. You will want to try running one of the queries outside of the "combo box environment" and start your debugging. There is no simple fix that anyone here is going to be able to give you based on such limited information.

Comment: @braX apologies for limited information as I have never coded in VBA , so thought of asking here at stackoverflow.

Comment: Does it work if you just change it to `DoCmd.OpenQuery Me.cboChooseQuery`? Which query was chosen? You can find out if you change it to `MsgBox Me.cboChooseQuery` - that should at least get you started. Once you know which query was being opened, you can open it manually at see if the same thing happens.

Comment: @braX I just hard coded the string value without all parameters and got some other error "3051" which is access denied to a file. not sure why second and third parameter is causing errors but i am in the right direction.

Comment: It is most likely due to some other changes that happened to your network, or your permissions then, unrelated to which version of Windows or Office that you are using. You may want to ask your IT department, assuming you have one.

Comment: @braX I am saying that `DoCmd.OpenQuery Me.cboChooseQuery` works but `DoCmd.OpenQuery Me.cboChooseQuery, acViewNormal, acReadOnly` gives 3270 error, so wondering why adding `acViewNormal, acReadOnly` fails but it used to work https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.openquery

Comment: https://www.nucleustechnologies.com/blog/how-to-fix-access-database-error-3270/

Comment: @braX found something strange, if I hard code string value after `DoCmd.OpenQuery "query"` then it works. If I revert the code back to original code `DoCmd.OpenQuery Me.cboChooseQuery, acViewNormal, acReadOnly` once the hard coded query worked, any subsequent query works but if I close the report and re-open vba throws 3270 error. very weird issue.